# Как избежать определения двух методов/конструкторов с одинаковыми параметрами?

Tags: java, методы, конструктор, полиморфизм

Например, пишу класс `Vector`. Вполне естественно создавать объект, принимая в конструктор или координаты `x` и `y`, или же принимая длину вектора и угол между направлением вектора и положительным направлением оси OX. Однако я не могу написать так:

```
public class Vector {
    float x;
    float y;

    public Vector(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Vector(float length, float alpha) {
        this.x = length*Math.cos(alpha);
        this.y = length*Math.sin(alpha);
    }
}
```

Компилятор, конечно, будет ругаться на неоднозначность в определении конструкторов. Я не могу её избежать переставив аргументы местами, так как они одинаковых типов. Что делать в таких ситуациях, когда метод/конструктор должен принимать два разных по смыслу набора параметров, но получается так, что они имеют одинаковые типы?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В таких случаях не лишним будет использование статических фабричных методов. С использованием этого шаблона ваш код будет выглядить так:

```
public static class Vector {
    public final float x;
    public final float y;

    private Vector(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Vector coordinate(float x, float y) {
        return new Vector(x, y);
    }

    public static Vector radian(float length, float alpha) {
        return new Vector(length * Math.cos(alpha), length * Math.sin(alpha);)
    }
}
```

Так же, можно воспользоваться шаблоном проектирования `builder`. Здесь он выглядит немного громоздко, но в принципе, тоже применим:

```
public static class Vector {

    ...

    public static VectorBuilder builder() {
        return new VectorBuilder();
    }

    public static class VectorBuilder {
        private double length;
        private double alpha;
        private float x;
        private float y;

        public VectorBuilder setLength(float length) {
            this.length = length;
            compute();
            return this;
        }
        public VectorBuilder setAlpha(float alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            compute();
            return this;
        }
        private void compute() {
            this.x = (float) (length * Math.cos(alpha));
            this.y = (float) (length * Math.sin(alpha));
        }

        public VectorBuilder setX(float x) {
            this.x = x;
            return this;
        }
        public VectorBuilder setY(float y) {
            this.y = y;
            return this;
        }
        public Vector build() {
            return new Vector(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вроде фабрики:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    float setX(float x, float y);
    float setY(float x, float y);
}

class Vector {
    float x;
    float y;
    static SomeInterface case1 = new SomeInterface() {
        @Override
        public float setX(float x, float y) {
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        public float setY(float x, float y) {
            return y;
        }
    };

    static SomeInterface case2 = new SomeInterface() {
        @Override
        public float setX(float x, float y) {
            return  x * (float) Math.cos(y);
        }

        @Override
        public float setY(float x, float y) {
            return  x * (float) Math.sin(y);
        }
    };

    public Vector(float x, float y, SomeInterface someInterface) {
        this.x = someInterface.setX(x,y);
        this.y = someInterface.setY(x,y);
    }
}

.
.
.
 new Vector(1.0f, 2.0f, Vector.case1);
 new Vector(1.0f, 2.0f, Vector.case2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете добавить костыль в виде третьего параметра и оставить один конструктор:

```
public Vector(float a, float b, boolean isCoordinates)  {
  if (isCoordinates) {
    this.x = a;
    this.y = b;
  } else {
    this.x = a*Math.cos(b);
    this.y = a*Math.sin(b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Может так?

```
public class Vector {
    float x;
    float y;

    public Vector(float[] ху) {
        this.x = ху[0];
        this.y = ху[1];
    }

    public Vector(float length, float alpha) {
        this.x = length*Math.cos(alpha);
        this.y = length*Math.sin(alpha);
    }
}
```